# Corsair void pro wireless compatibility

Tags: 20.04, headphones

To keep it short im using the corsair void pro wireless headset on ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to control the lighting and check how much battery I have left. I saw a reddit post saying to use git to check my battery life but im really new to linux so I dont really understand what that means. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found this project, which seems to have the capabilities you are looking for.

https://github.com/Sapd/HeadsetControl

Follow the project's own instructions:
download dependencies first, then build it.